# Can't access container IP from host docker for windows stack

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows

I'm using the following docker compose file to build my docker swarm stack that have windows containers deployed in a Windows 10:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  service1:
    image: myrepository/dotnet-framework:3.5-windowsservercore
    environment:
      - my_path="C:/app/build/app.exe"
      - my_arg= 1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.id == asdfasdgasgasg
    volumes:
      - service1:C:/app
  service1:
    image: myrepository/dotnet-framework:3.5-windowsservercore
    ports:
      - target: 7878
        published: 7878
        mode: host
    environment:
      - my_path="C:/app/app.exe"
      - my_arg= 2
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.id == asdfasdgasgasg
    volumes:
      - service1:C:/app

volumes:
  service2:
    external:
      name: service1
  service1:
    external:
      name: service1
```

As you can see `service2` is listening in port `7878`. I know, as is shown in [this](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/) post, that I can't reach this port using `localhost:7878`. Thus I run the command `docker inspect containerID` to figure out the IP address of the container.

[image]

If I ping the container `service2` from `service1`, it responds. But If I try to access the port `10.0.3.18:7878` from the host, there's no response. How could I reach port 7878from the hots? On the other hand, I have Linux containers that must reach the 'service2' windows container.

Comment: Did you verify that something is running on port 7898? You said you tried to ping IP address but you did not check if port is listening

Comment: @GregorySuvalian thanks for the comment. I can ping from the other container. But the ping from the host to the container doesn' work.

Comment: Ping might or might not work due to various firewalls in between. What matters if port works

Comment: @GregorySuvalian there aren't firewalls between containers, all of them are mounted in the same host. In addition, form the container `service2` I can reach port 7878.

Comment: I forgot Localhost never worked on that same server. Try to access it from outside

Comment: I can't access it from outside :(. Only with between containers.

Comment: From outside you need to use IP address of the host and not container. As you can see you published port in `host` mode

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm using the IP of the host. Moreover, I set the port rules to the router and I tried to access from swarm manager that is in an AWS EC2 instance using the public IP `curl publicIp:7878`. I think that is some kind of issue that I can't understand with the overlay network that uses swarm. I run the container as `docker run -it -p 7878:7878 .....` and I can reach the container port 7878

Comment: Try to put `deploy:
      mode: global`. Windows containers are supported only in global and not replicated mode as far as I know and default is replicated

Comment: It doesn't work. I ran `netstat -ab` in the host where the container is deployed in global mode and this is the result:  `[com.docker.localhost-forwarder.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7878         gateway-bbb-aaa:0  LISTENING
 [com.docker.localhost-forwarder.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7878         gateway-bbb-aaa:57767  CLOSE_WAIT
 [com.docker.localhost-forwarder.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7878         gateway-bbb-aaa:64397  ESTABLISHED`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Windows updated and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the docker containers in the service can communicate with each other by default as they are started up on their own private network. That is why you can ping between the service containers.

The port 7878 you opened up will also be accessible to the host windows 10 os via the host machine’s ip address not the container ip address. The container’s IP address is private even to the host os.

Ping may not work as you have not opened up the ping port in the service and there may not be a ping service in the image to respond to your ping request. I may be wrong on this last point. Ping is not a good method to verify if a container is working or not.